# MongoDB window closes automatically when I try to open

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7

I'm trying to install MangoDB in my windows machine 64-bit. I'm following official documentation to install the same. I have installed successfully as stated and stuck at Run MongoDB section at step 2.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

When I run the file "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe" window opens and automatically closes. Not sure why this is happening, I Googled and tried troubleshooting the same but no luck. I even added MongoDB path to windows environment variables as well. But still it doesn't work.

Anyone faced this issue? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to specify more options on the command line when running the server. Open a command line window rather than just clicking on the executable. There are clear examples and instruction in the documentation page you reference.

Answer (score 20):

from [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#set-up-the-mongodb-environment):

> MongoDB requires a data directory to store all data. MongoDB’s default
>   data directory path is \data\db. Create this folder using the
>   following commands from a Command Prompt:
>
> md \data\db
>
> You can specify an alternate path for data files using the
>   --dbpath option to mongod.exe, for example:
>
> C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data

The reason of your problem is that you don't have that data directory.

Comment: what directory does "data/db" need to be in?

Comment: @icaughtfireonce I created it as a sibling to mongod.exe - worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

Create a folder named '**data**' with sub-folder '**db**' in the root of the folder where your MongoDB Server is installed.

Like in my case, it was installed on ***C:/Program Files/MongoDB/*** and the mongod.exe, mongo.exe resides in ***C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.0/bin/***.

So, I created a folder namely "**data**" and a sub-folder in it namely "**db**".

> **C:/data/db**

Sometimes, there might be a chance that "**data**" folder already exists in the root drive. Then, just create a sub-folder named "**db**" in it.

After all of this, close **mongod.exe** & **mongo.exe** if running. And open them again in order to see if the problem is gone! I hope that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As laike9m said, MongoDB requires the directory data/db to be created. I just solved the same problem and I did it by creating the directory in "C:/ " (working on windows).

Answer (score 1):

Yep I ran into the same problem. go to the root of the drive that mongo is installed 'I had mongo installed on drive I:' so I clicked on drive I: and then I created a folder and called it **data** then I created another folder and called it **db**. note it has to be done right at the root so as soon as you click onto the drive if you try to put it in another folder on the drive Mongo will not be able to find it.